# ¿Como solucionar el error Mixed Content url was loaded over HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, razor

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Me aparece el siguiente error al realizar el inicio de sesión.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://url/titulo' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://url/titulo/Acceso/ValidarUsuario'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

En mi aplicación yo obtengo el url de la aplicación de la siguiente manera

```
<!--Obtener Url de aplicacion-->
    @{
        String base_url = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(
            new Uri(
                new Uri(this.Context.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)),
                Url.Content("~/")
            ).ToString());
        if (base_url == "/")
        {
            base_url = "";
        }
        //String ruta = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
    }
<input type="hidden" id="hdn_root" value="@base_url" />
```

Pero al imprimir en consola mapea la url base pero como http y no como https y me parece que desde ahi es donde surge el problema.

Asi se muestra la url en la web.

```
https://app.ejemplo.com/SeguimientoDS
```

Esto es lo que se obtiene del método.

```
http://app.ejemplo.com:51151/SeguimientoDS
```

Comment: Estás intentando pegarle a una página http desde un dominio https, tenés que ajustar tu llamada para que también sea https, o pegarle todo a un dominio no seguro (http)

Comment: Estimado, cómo sería la llamada para obtener el https

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Comment: Pero la url se debería mapear dinámicamente